# Finding a proof for a cyclic three variables inequality.

Tags: inequality

> **Problem.** Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $a+b+c=1.$ Prove that $$a\sqrt{a^2+4b}+b\sqrt{b^2+4c}+c\sqrt{c^2+4a}\ge 1.$$

I'm looking for a proof for my predictive problem. I think that it's true but I have no proof.

There's interesting fact about equality cases. I checked that equality holds iff $abc=0.$

Indeed, let $c=0;a+b=1.$ The inequality becomes$$a\sqrt{a^2+4(1-a)}+(1-a)(1-a)=a(2-a)+(1-a)^2= 1.$$

If we use $c\ge 0 \implies a+b\le 1$ then it suffices to prove $$a\sqrt{a^2+4b}+b\sqrt{b^2}\ge 1,$$which is totally wrong.

Any helps will be desired. Thank you.

Comment: @CalvinLin I meant equality holds when there;s at least one variable equal $0.$

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you like one liner?

$\sum_{cyc}a \sqrt{a^2+4b}=\sum_{cyc}a \sqrt{(a+2b)^2+4bc} \geq \sum_{cyc}a(a+2b)=1$

OMG

Beautiful inequality problem.

Comment: Beautiful proof! It turns out one line, haha!